# Override System Pattern/number Lock from Lock Screen Android

Tags: android

I have to create lock screen for Android phones which override the system lock, when i swipe my lock screen it will directly ask to user to open lock. currently it is opening system lock screen and i have to swipe again after my lock screen Swipe.

Is there any way to do that when i swipe my Lock Screen, it will open direct phone home screen if no lock applied, or open pattern or num pad screen if lock applied.

Please help us.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be anything you need to program. But you can turn off the default lock completely.

Go to Settings > lockscreen and security > type lockscreen > none

This may not be exactly the same for all phones. I am using a Galaxy S6 with android 5.

Most custom lockscreen apps ask you to turn off your default lockscreen as well.

Hope it helps!

e: I am reading your question again, and it may be that I don't understand the question correctly. sorry about that if that is the case.